# Custom sorting in javascript ,sorting based on another field

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I have some information like this, these are not objects ..just individual data

```
name : 'element1', x: 30, y : 35
name : 'element2', x : 10, y:16
name : 'element3', x: 70, y:11
```

i have pushed all three infos to three different arrays

```
var elmArray = ['element1','element2','element3'];
var xArray = [30, 10, 70];    
var yArray = [35, 16, 11];
```

sorted the `xArray` and `yArray` in `asc` order like this

```
xArray.sort(function(a, b){return a - b});
yArray.sort(function(a, b){return a - b});
```

My question is how do I sort the `elmArray` with respect to `xArray` and `yArray`
for example after `xArray` sort I want `elmArray` like this

```
['element2', 'element1', 'element3'];
```

and after `yArray` I want it like this

```
['element3', 'element2', 'element1'];
```

Comment: Why are you sorting all the keys individually? Why not sort the array of objects?

Comment: *"I have some information like this ,these are not objects ..just individual data"* - if the data is related then they should be objects! Related could mean that you want to sort one in respect of the other.

Comment: This is a duplicate of countless questions.

Comment: have a look at this, https://github.com/Teun/thenBy.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start with, you *must* make your data into an array of objects.

```
var arr = [
    {name : 'element1' ,x: 30, y : 35},
    {name : 'element2', x : 10, y:16},
    {name :'element3', x: 70, y:11}];
```

Then you know how to sort an array!

```
arr.sort(function(a,b){ return a.x - b.x; } ); // sort by x
```

Once sorted, if you want an array containing just one property you can use `.map`

```
var names = arr.map(function(e) { return e.name; });
```

Answer (score 3):

Sort them as objects:

```
var array = [
    {name : 'element1' ,x: 30, y:35 },
    {name : 'element2', x: 10, y:16 },
    {name : 'element3', x: 70, y:11 }
]

var sorted = array.sort(function (prev, next) { return prev.x - next.x });
```

if you want individual portions of data:

```
var elements = sorted.map(function (e) { return e.name });
```

Comment: Well, it actually does, here is citation from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) - _The sort() method sorts the elements of an array in place and returns the array._

Answer (score 3):

```js
var elmarray = ['element1','element2','element3'];
var xarray = [30,10,70];    
var yarray = [35,16,11];
finalArray = sort(xarray, elmarray);
xarray = finalArray.first;
elmarray = finalArray.second;
console.log(xarray);
console.log(elmarray);

function sort(a, b){
   for (var index = 0; index < a.length-1; index += 1) {
            nextIndex = index + 1;
            if (a[index] > a[nextIndex]) {
                holder1 = a[nextIndex];
                holder2 = b[nextIndex];
                
                a[nextIndex] = a[index];
                b[nextIndex] = b[index];
                
                a[index] = holder1;
                b[index] = holder2;
              }
        }
    return { first: a,
            second: b}
}
```

also see http://jsfiddle.net/et5zL3ve/